# Why eclipse continuously shows "processing build path changes"?

Tags: eclipse

I have around 40 maven projects added in eclipse. It was working fine till i restarted my laptop. After restarting laptop and starting eclipse continuously shows "processing build path changes". Its showing from last 3 hours.

It's not allowing me to do any other activity as other activity gets added back to stack. I tried restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be Eclipse [Bug 417094](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417094)
Some dead lock happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your workspace, there is a eclipse folder called `.metadata`. Delete the file inside called `.lock`, after that restart your eclipse, it should back to normal now.